# How to copy value from a line in a file and paste it into a new file using Shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a file containing my personal details (.txt). How can I, via a shell script, copy only a few lines in the file and bring it to a new .txt file?.

```
Name: Nik
Date of Birth: 5.06.92
Address: 1234 Main St.
SSN: 123-45-6789
```

I would like to copy my address `1234 Main St.` to another file.

Comment: I highly recommend using a better format for your date storage.  Perhaps something more like `05.06.1992`.

Comment: `grep '^Address:' file > file.out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
awk -F': ' '/^Address/{print $2}' personalinfo.txt | tee newfile.txt
```

Comment: You left out the part where you write that output to a new file.

Comment: Corrected.  Thanks.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Thanks it worked. How can i give the output of above command as a variable input value for other command?

Comment: The pipe character `|` passes the output of one command to the next. In this case the output of `awk` is being passed to `tee`, which writes this output into a new file `newfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a specific line by its number :

```
sed -n '1 p' personal_details.txt > newfile.txt # Where 1 is the line number
```

If you want to copy a line  by its contents :

```
grep 'Name' personal_details.txt > newfile.txt
```

If you want to copy a line but only its value, not the name of the field:

```
awk -F':' '/^Name/ {print $2}'  personal_details.txt > newfile.txt
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you would like to use only `grep` or `pcregrep` (in case you are on a macOS):

```
grep -oP "Address: \K.+" file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Or in macOS:

```
pcregrep -o "Address: \K.+" file.txt > newfile.txt
```

The `\K` can be read as exclude everything at the left before it and return only the right part `.+`